# In .NET, why is a reference to an interface's assembly needed if the interface is never used?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

If project A has an interface A, and project B has a class B that implements interface A, then project B needs a reference to project A.

In project B:

```
public class B : A
{
    void A.MethodA()
    {
    }
}
```

But if project C uses class B, without ever using it as the interface A (so no code that calls A's method on an instance of B or casts an instance of B to A), then it must still reference project A. Even if project B explicitly implements interface A (as the example code above does).

In project C:

```
public class C
{
    public C()
    {
       var b = new B(); 
    }
}
```

The result is:

> The type 'A' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You
>   must add a reference to assembly 'A, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.

Why is that?

Comment: What would happen if you called `typeof(B).GetInterfaces()` without actually having those types available? The internal model of .NET means that even interfaces are types, and that all types that an application needs are available at runtime. Even if you can imagine a way to get rid of what you believe are "not-really-types" and have the runtime cope with that, you're probably just ignoring many edge cases like the one I just mentioned.

Comment: You could try to come up with scenarios where B is sufficient.  But that's not very productive, there's a much simpler explanation.  Suppose that A was updated and the interface acquired another method.  And B was not.  You'd now leave a gaping hole if you wouldn't add the A reference:  C would not implement the interface correctly and you wouldn't get a compile error.  That of course is intolerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that all .Net is accessible thru Reflection so everything must be available to be queried by the Reflection queries.

And how you will cast the class to the interface directly implementing it if it is not available in project C?

Comment: It must be available at runtime, sure. But the compiler does not obviously need the reference assembly. The C# compiler does not use the CLR to load types.

Comment: @usr: the only reason to have a direct implementation is to use it by casting to the interface so if you don't know how to cast the interface you wouldn't have available some functionality of the class.